# Offloading backups to secondary network

Tags: networking, ip, vlan

I'm trying to solve a problem- Currently, we are constantly backing up and have no budget for additional servers. Our production network is still a 10/100 and handles voip, SQL plus our backup traffic, and I'd like to offload the backup traffic onto a secondary network- all of our servers have secondary NIC's that are not in use, and all support gigabit (Our switching hardware does not- a topic for another day). I'd like to move my backups off the production network, but I am having a hard time getting the computers to communicate. I am using a Netgear GS724T switch for the backup network- Chosen for cost and because I have used them extensively on networks saturated with ghosting traffic, so I know it's up to the task. I have defined a VLAN, with ports that are not members of any other VLAN. All traffic is untagged on the VLAN. I have set the servers with 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.1.11 addresses, 255.255.255.0 netmask and I have tried a blank GW, using the local IP of the server 192.168.1.whatever address, and I have tried using the switch's production-side IP as the GW. The machines cannot find each other. DNS addresses are blank because I am going purely by IP for now... Any ideas how to get these machines to talk? they are Windows machines, running Server 2008R2 and 2003R2.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say troubleshoot from the ground up, and start off by connecting the machines directly to each other( since it's gbit you don't have to worry about crossover cables).  No GW is necessary since it's not going to be a routed network.  I would check the routing table on the machines to make sure it picked up the new IP's correctly, IIRC:

`route print`

will display the routing table, just make sure there is an entry for the 192.168.1.0/24 network and that it's using the correct interface.  If this is working then somethings up with the switch config, I'd set that up with the default all ports untagged to vlan 1, for testing.

Also, how are you testing connectivity between the machines?  Connection / activity lights? JIC.

Comment: I was using arp -a and not seeing the MAC addresses for each other. Did factory reset on switch and they are talking. Do I need to mess with lag and pvids or should I just remove those two port from the default vlan and define a new vlan that contains only those two untagged ports? I'm using link lights then speed/duplex, ping test, file access, remote install, and successful back as my criteria.